# Exception in Login:: Could not create connection to database server

Tags: java, android, sql, jdbc, amazon-web-services

I'm working on an android application (API level 19) that connects to a database on AWS and I keep getting the following error:

```
    04-29 09:24:12.095: I/System.out(1711): Exception in Login::Could not create connection to database server.
    04-29 09:24:12.095: W/System.err(1711): com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
```

I have a class called DataBaseConnection that handles the connection:

```
public class DataBaseConnection {

Connection connect = null;

public Connection getDataBaseConnection(){
    if(connect == null){
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");// loading MySQL driver
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://cmpe277.c38qsf0avgvg.us-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/CMPE277?user=root&password=password");
            //Set up connection with DB, username, password
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Login::"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return connect;
}
}
```

And the onClick method to connect to the database and insert values looks like this:

```
//onClick Method for Sign Up
public void signUp(View view){

    DataBaseConnection dbConn = new DataBaseConnection();
    Connection conn = dbConn.getDataBaseConnection();

    EditText usernameEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    username = usernameEntry.getText().toString();

    EditText password1Entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
    password1 = password1Entry.getText().toString();

    EditText password2Entry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password2);
    password2 = password2Entry.getText().toString();

    //Check That the two Typed Passwords Match
    if(password1.equals(password2)){
        query = "INSERT INTO USER VALUES (username,password1)";
        try {
                if(conn != null){
                    stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    stmt.executeQuery(query);
                }
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error in execute query::"+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have used this class (DataBaseConnection) within a Java application without problems but when I try to implement it in an android app I run into errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. Simply ran the connection to the database in a separate thread using AsyncTask